# Punctuation mark before a closing quote mark (Children's picture book)

Tags: grammar

I’m writing a children's picture book and enjoy the illustration element but struggle with the writing side. When using an online grammar checker I get the following error for the text below:

*“In dialogue you should always have a punctuation mark, usually a comma before a closing quote mark.”*

This is my text.

> James once asked the cat, “have you seen another person like me?”.  The cat crossed his legs and thought for a while, then replied, “I’ve scratched lots of trees, but I’ve never seen a boy like you”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> James once asked the cat, “Have you seen another person like me?”
>
> The cat crossed his legs and thought for a while, then replied, “I’ve scratched lots of trees, but I’ve never seen a boy like you.”

The above would follow the rule you cited. No addition period is needed after the question mark closing the first quote.

Additionally, it follows the rule that there is at most [one speaker per paragraph](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/6977/must-every-piece-of-speech-get-its-own-paragraph).